# Wordpress - Display child pages in a loop on their parent pages

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I would know how to display child pages in a grid loop (preferably in alphabetical order) on a parent page *and* I'd need to know whether I simply need to edit an existing template (if so, which template?) or create a new template to achieve this. Keep in mind that I am brand new to php, so thorough answers would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please display what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello. I have not tried anything. I don't want to mess anything up. I  don't even know how to create a separate loop from the main loop, much less using pages instead of posts.

Comment: If you can at least tell me which template to edit, I can try my hand.